# Hamming Distance in Block Parity

Tags: hamming-distance

I´m sitting here and I´m not able to solve a problem related to the hamming distance.

I have a block like this:

```
100
000
111
```

When I use the vertical redundancy Check now I get:

```
100-1
000-0
111-1
||| |
011-0
```

because I add an 1 to each row and column, if I have an odd number of 1´s or I add an 0 to each row and column, if i have an odd number of 0´s.

Now I should have 6 words right?

```
w1: 1001
w2: 0000
w3: 1110
w4: 1010
w5: 0011
w6: 0011
```

Are the created (through VRC) bits words too? So are `1000` and `0110` words too?

If I compare the words and check the Hamming Distance, I get an minimal Hamming Distance of 2 (0 should not count, because if the Hamming Distance is 0, the words are the same). E.g. compare w1 and w2. 
In our lecture, the professor said, that the Hamming Distance for this example is 3. How can it be 3?!

Were is my mistake? :-(

I hope someone can help me. 
Have a great Sunday!

Comment: So apparently you have to delete the parity bit on the bottom right. Than you have to get the Hamming Distance from all the rows as well as the columns. Than you have to add 1 to the Hamming Distance you got from the rows and from the columns. Here it would be 3.
In case of a 3x3 block, the Hamming Distance would be always 3!

In my opinion this solution is a bit strange... 
(got the solution from a fellow student)

Comment: Adding a `0` to `111` is wrong. After you have added the parity bit you must have an even number of `1`'s, and in this case you don't. The correct one is: for `111` add `1`. Other than that, I don't know what your professor means or wants, but the Hamming distance between w1 and w2 is 2, not 3.

Comment: Oh yeah. I corrected it. 
Yes, the Hamming Distance between w1 and w2 ist 2. But my fellow student meant, that the Hamming Distance of the WHOLE block is 3, because we deleted the parity bit on the bottom right... So we get the Hamming Distance of the block and add (randomly) 1... this is so strange :-(